# Clicking System Tray icon(Volume) using pywinauto

Tags: python

How to click System Tray icon(Volume) using PywinAuto

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example how to click first button. Using info.text you can try to find Volume button.

```
from pywinauto import taskbar

sti = taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.WrapperObject()

print 'Clicking ', sti.Button(0).info.text
sti.Button(0).Click()
```